# Basic Boost::asio TCP client

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I'm trying to create basic async TCP client that outputs anything it receives. This is my code:

```
class tcp_client
{
private:
  std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket;
  std::array<char, 1024> recv_buf;

public:
  tcp_client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
  {     
        socket = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(io_service);
        socket->connect(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 2522));

        start_receive();
  }

private:
  void start_receive()
  {

    socket->async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf),
        boost::bind(&tcp_client::handle_receive, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
        std::cout << "handling receive: " << error << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::string(recv_buf.data()) << std::endl;

        start_receive();
  }

};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp_client client(io_service);
    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

It's pretty straightforward:

1. Socket is created and connected to local port 2522 (this is probably where the error originates)
2. Socket is set to async_receive and is set to have a handler (this part is never reached, though)
3. The handler is set to handle the received data and restart socket

The code produces the following runtime error:

```
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >: connect: Connection refused
```

Comment: And you did *read* the message? What do you think it means when it say "connect: Connection refused"? There *is* something listening on TCP port 2522 on localhost?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The message is not outputet as the handle_receive is never reached. There is nothing on port 2522, it should be free. (at least that's what netcat says). Changing to different port doesn't alter the error code.

Comment: Do you have any program to connect to? I mean, you have a client, but no server. Except if you just didn't post it, you should have another piece of code to connect to. If you are looking for an example, you may refer to boost.asio chat example ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp11_examples )

Comment: "Connection refused" means that your `socket->connect(...)` call *failed*. If there's nothing to connect to, how would that ever succeed? How could the program ever continue? You probably need to learn a little more basics about how TCP works.

Comment: Ok, this was dumb of me. I was running netcat as the "server side" but was actually using a different port. Thatnk you all who commented here, this should be closed now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if you post an answer saying that the server side must be **properly** set up, it'll get accepted.